# LCD only showing black blocks when built - *** simulation on Proteus works fine ***

Tags: c, lcd

I am coding a program this displays time on a LCD. I'm using is LM016L (16x2 LCD display) The simulations works fine in Proteus but when i build it it does not work and on powering it up the LCD only shows black blocks across the whole top row. i am using mcc18 complier. i am using a PIC18f2620 but i have also tried a PIC18f4520 but still having the same issues. i am also using ds1307 Real time clock and a crystal for the real time clock (not sure if this matters). i am assuming the PIC is working correctly because when i press a button in the circuit the LED lights up but the LCD still remains to do nothing but display the black blocks. i have also tried adjusting the manual contrast of the LCD but no luck.

Here is Frame.c where the LCD is initialised and used

```
#include <xlcd.h>
#include <delays.h>

#include "Frame.h"
#include "Misc.h"
#include "I2C.h"
#include "EEPROM.h"

void InitLCD()
    {  
       OpenXLCD(FOUR_BIT & LINES_5X7);

       while (BusyXLCD());

       WriteCmdXLCD(0x06);  // Entry Mode (Increment DDRAAM Loc)
       WriteCmdXLCD(0b00001100);
    }

    void Splash(int* frame)
    {
       int c;
       char nameMsg[] = "** MediSync **";
       char loadingMsg1[] = "Loading";
       char loadingMsg2[] = "Loading.";
       char loadingMsg3[] = "Loading..";
       char loadingMsg4[] = "Loading...";

       SetDDRamAddr(0x01);
       putsXLCD(nameMsg);

       SetDDRamAddr(0x44);
       putsXLCD(loadingMsg1);
       for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++) Delay10KTCYx(6);

       SetDDRamAddr(0x44);
       putsXLCD(loadingMsg2);
       for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++) Delay10KTCYx(5);

       SetDDRamAddr(0x44);
       putsXLCD(loadingMsg3);
       for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++) Delay10KTCYx(5);

       SetDDRamAddr(0x44);
       putsXLCD(loadingMsg4);
       for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++) Delay10KTCYx(5);

      // WriteDS1307(0x02, 0b0010001); // set hour to 11
       //WriteDS1307(1, 0b01011001); // set minute to 59
       ap = 1;

       // Get reminder saved in memory
       count_min = count_min_tmp = EEPROM_Read(MEM_MINUTES);
       count_hr = count_hr_tmp = EEPROM_Read(MEM_HOURS);

       // Get time saved in DS1307
       hour_bcd = ReadDS1307(0x02);
       minute_bcd = ReadDS1307(0x01);

       hour = BCD2Bin(hour_bcd);
       minute = BCD2Bin(minute_bcd);

       WriteDS1307(0, 0x00); // reset seconds to 0
       TMR0L = 0;

       WriteDS1307(7, 0b00010010); // Start square wave on ds1307 & 8.192kHz

       *frame = HOME;

       gMode = MODE_DEFAULT;
    }
```

Help would be really appreciated!

if you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Qestions involving special hardware are always a problem here. We just cannot check the hardware is working properly, nor if there are other issues. Nevertheless, you are expected to provide a [mcve] which your code clear is not. Also read [ask]. We are no debugging service.

Comment: the hardware seems to be working fine. i have tested the hardware using other programs and individually they are working.

Comment: To add to what Olaf said - your example is huge. Get your example down to tiny - the minimum required - hence the [mcve] notation.

Comment: i have made some adjustments to the code displayed and now displaying example of the first bit of code that should be displayed. hope this better helps

Comment: Did you adjust all the io port defines in xlcd.h according to your hardware?